# Sharing custom image FAMILY publicly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I can see from documentation how to [Sharing custom images publicly](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/managing-access-custom-images#share-images-publicly) but it doesn't seem like it's possible to either grant public access to all images or at by family basis.

It seem something like that should've work but **it didn't work**:

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project-id \
  --member 'allAuthenticatedUsers' --role 'roles/compute.imageUser'
```

In my case I'd like to create a project specifically for image sharing across GCP platform for our customers without the need to add each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The command in your question is trying to grant the permission `roles/compute.imageUser` to the project for `allAuthenticatedUsers`. That specific authorization is not supported.

Instead grant the permission on the resource. Use the following command:

```
gcloud compute images add-iam-policy-binding <IMAGE> --member=allAuthenticatedUsers --role=roles/compute.imageUser
```

[gcloud compute images add-iam-policy-binding](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/add-iam-policy-binding)

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned I saw that command but I'm interested if it's possible to give access either to a **image family** or all images at once.

Comment: @fkorotkov As I mentioned in my answer you cannot. You can only add permissions to a resource and only certain resources, not a group or family or resources to `allauthenticatedUsers`.